# How to send a string (that is in a loop) from client to server only one time per a minute?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a string that is in a while loop to be sent from client to server multiple times but I want it to be sent only one time per a minute. How can I do it, any ideas !!?
Here is the code:

```
    String str= " ";
    try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\bluetooth.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

             while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            if ( str.equals.("F81EDF5B0CC7")) // "F81EDF5B0CC7" is a String that I have it in the text file 'bluetooth.txt'
                {
                  out.writeUTF(str);
             }
            } 
            in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried Thread.sleep(60000)

Comment: I don't understand if you want to schedule the sending of some strings, i.e. send it every minute or you want to limit the rate, so no more than one string is send every minute.

Comment: @jclozano I'm not using thread here and actually the line `str.equals.("F81EDF5B0CC7")` has not a static value as it shown (I do that for minimizing the lines of code). So I don't want to pause the entire operation.

Comment: @binary_runner The first one :) schedule the sending of some strings

Comment: Even if you aren't using thread, by implementing a separate thread only for sending, you could use it to make sure it gets sent only once each minute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(..)`

```
int delay =9;   // delay for 0 sec - start immediatelly
int period = 60000;  // repeat every 60 sec.
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        // Task here ...
    }
}, delay, period);
```

Taken from [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/ScheduleRepeat.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I think this will pause the entire process and my purpose is to pause sending one single string after it have been sent.

Comment: Actually no. Timer runs it's tasks in a separate thread(s), it does not block the main thread where you started it: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: You could put your `while(){..}` loop inside the `run(){}` method (including `String str=` declaration.).

Comment: I think you didn't get my point, what I want is only to pause `str` after `if ( str.equals.("F81EDF5B0CC7"))`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the scheduled executor service ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html ), tutorial in ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html )